# Adding a suffix to a form element

Tags: forms

I have a form which has an input field for which i want to add a suffix.

```
function myapp_preprocess_form_element(&$variables) {
  if ($variables["element"]["#attributes"]["id"] == 'edit-keys') {
    $variables['#suffix'] = '<div>Some text</div>';
  }
}
```

I've looked into the `form-element.html.twig` file and it does have a `suffix` varaible, but it's not rendering.

Any ideas?

Comment: `$variables["element"]["suffix"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter() for login.
 */
function MYTHEME_form_user_login_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['register_user']['#prefix'] = "<div class=\"form-footer\"> <span>" . t("Don't have an account?") . "</span>";
  $form['register_user']['#suffix'] = "</div>";
}
```

This is how I've added a wrapper to a form element using prefix and suffix. Hope it helps.